# Compare different elements in two different lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to compare if 2 different data are matching from different lists.

I have those 2 lists and I need to count the numbers of babies with :

```
first_name_baby = S AND age_baby = 1 
age_baby = [ 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3].  first_name_baby= [ T, S, R, T, O, A, L, S, F, S, Z, U, S, P]
```

There is actually 2 times when `first_name_baby = S AND age_baby = 1` but I need to write a Python program for that.

Comment: where is the second list?

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Thank you. I tried that : if first_name_baby[i] == "S"  and age_baby[i]=="1" :
           count ()

Answer (score 2):

Use `zip` to combine corresponding list entries and then `.count`

```
>>> age_baby = [ 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3]
>>> first_name_baby = "T, S, R, T, O, A, L, S, F, S, Z, U, S, P".split(', ')
>>> list(zip(first_name_baby, age_baby)).count(('S', 1))
2
```

Alternatively, you could use numpy. This would allow a solution very similar to what you have tried:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>>                                                                                                             
>>> age_baby = np.array(age_baby)                                                    
>>> first_name_baby = np.array(first_name_baby)                                      
>>>                                                                                                                 
>>> np.count_nonzero((first_name_baby == 'S') & (age_baby == 1))                                      
2
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just take the sum of `1` whenever the conditions match. iterate over the lists simultaneously using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
# need to make sense of the names
T, S, R, O, A, L, F, Z, U, S, P = 'T, S, R, O, A, L, F, Z, U, S, P'.split(', ')
age_baby = [2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3]
first_name_baby = [T, S, R, T, O, A, L, S, F, S, Z, U, S, P]


sum(1 for age, name in zip(age_baby, first_name_baby) 
    if age == 1 and name == S)
```

---

thanks to [Austin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8472377/austin) a more elegant version of this:

```
sum(age == 1 and name == S for age, name in zip(age_baby, first_name_baby))
```

this works because bools in python are subclasses of `int` and `True` is basically `1` (with overloaded `__str__` and `__repr__`) and `False` is `0`; therefore the booleans can just be summed and the result is the number of `True` comparisons.

Comment: Or just: `sum(age == 1 and name =='S' for age, name in zip(age_baby, first_name_baby))`.

Comment: @Austin oh, thanks! never thought of that. updated (hope that's fine for you).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> count = 0
>>> 
>>> 
>>> for i in range(len(first_name_baby)):
...   if first_name_baby[i] == 'S' and age_baby[i] == 1:
...     count += 1
... 
>>> count
2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = len([item for idx, item in enumerate(age_baby) if item == 1 and first_name_baby[idx] == 'S'])
```

> ```
> 2
> ```

Expanded:

```
l = []
for idx, item in enumerate(age_baby):
    if item == 1 and first_name_baby[idx] == 'S':
        l.append(item)
x = len(l)
```